# Appropriate way to handle slight variations of questions

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

What is the preferred method of getting answers to similar questions to the one you just asked?

Sometimes I'll get an answer that actually sparks new questions for me. But I feel like asking a whole new question would just be a hassle for the person who just answered if they were to answer the new one too, because they'd essentially be modifying their previous answer but porting it over to a new post. But on the other hand, you don't want the answer to multiple questions all in the same post.

For example, I recently asked for a SQL query that would achieve some desired goal. It included a condition like "only select users who have done event X". But then I realized that I also wanted to know how to do it without that, and I wanted to retrieve some different fields. (It wasn't necessarily a trivial modification, because these changes might have made it so a different query was actually a faster/more appropriate solution). The core of the solution would probably be the same, so a whole new question seemed like overkill, but including it in the same question seemed like stuffing the question with too much content. Are there any rules of thumb out there to help guide one in this case?

Comment: If you can ask the actual question without making it too broad, ask the actual question. Sometimes, the solution to a simpler instance of the problem may not map well to the actual question.

Comment: If you're truly using [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable examples](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and your problem statement is clear and to the point, then either the questions are the same questions, or they are different questions. If it is "Well, what if X condition", you could probably just ask the answerer, and if they educate you on the matter, you can edit the condition into the question and the answerer can do similar for their answer.